# How can a add a custom license to my dotnet nuget package?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, .net-standard, dotnet-cli

Today I tried to update my `netstandard2.0` class library and got a warning that the `<PackageLicenseUrl>` element is deprecated. After doing some research, I added the following lines to my `csproj` file:

```
<PackageLicenseFile>LICENSE.txt</PackageLicenseFile>

<!-- .... -->

<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\LICENSE.txt" Pack="true" PackagePath="$(PackageLicenseFile)"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Later, I tried to publish the package. `dotnet pack` runs without issue, but for `dotnet nuget push xxx.1.0.2.nupkg -k xxx -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` prints the following error:

```
info : "xxx.1.0.2.nupkg" wird per Push nach "'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package'" übertragen...
info :   PUT https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/
warn : Your API key expires in 1 days. Visit https://www.nuget.org/account/apikeys to regenerate your API key.
info :   BadRequest https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/ 1661 ms
error: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (License files are not yet supported.).
```

Summary:

- `PackageLicenseUrl` is deprecated but works
- `PackageLicenseFile` is not implemented

Did I miss something?

Comment: in case you don't get a notification of me editing/commenting on my answer, nuget.org is now accepting packages with licence files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new NuGet client shipped before the NuGetGallery depolyed support for the feature. But it should be [coming very soon](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7509#issuecomment-446030459). If you use a well known license, you can use the SDPX expression instead, and nuget.org will accept those already.

EDIT: nuget.org is now accepting packages with licence file. [Announcement of the new licence feature here](https://github.com/NuGet/Announcements/issues/32).

Comment: edited answer include link to announcement of NuGet's new licencing feature.